# Explicit interface implementation with tuple as interface generic not working

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

**Situation**:
I am trying to implement a specialized collection that assigns weights to items.
I can't use a `List<(T, double)>` as the collection needs to keep track of more information to provide special functionality.
However, this collection should implement `IList<(T, double)>`, so that I can use some extension methods.

**Approach**:

Implementing the interface works:

```
public class WeightedList<T> : IList<(T item, double weight)> 
{
    public void Add((T item, double weight) item)
    {
        this.Add(item.item, item.weight);
    }

    [...]
}
```

However, in order to keep the implementation clean, I want to implement a few of its methods explicitly.

```
public class WeightedList<T> : IList<(T item, double weight)> 
{
    // The method name Add is marked as source of error
    void IList<(T item, double weight)>.Add((T item, double weight) item)
    {
        this.Add(item.item, item.weight);
    }

    [...]
}
```

**Problem**:
But now, I suddenly get errors and it seems that the explicit interface implementation is not recognized anymore.

> Error CS0535 : 'WeightedList' does not implement interface member 'ICollection<(T item, double weight)>.Add((T item, double weight))'
>
> Error CS0539 : 'WeightedList.Add((T item, double weight))' in explicit interface declaration is not found among members of the interface that can be implemented

The only change I made, was changing the method to an explicit implementation.
This worked for me great so far, but using a tuple as interface generic seems to break it.
I also tried unnamed tuples for the interface (e.g. `IList<(T, double)>`) but that didn't change anything.

**Question**:
Why do I get these errors and how can I fix them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In an explicit interface implementation it's important to state the right interface:

```
public class WeightedList<T> : IList<(T item, double weight)> 
{
    // The method name Add is marked as source of error
    void ICollection<(T item, double weight)>.Add((T item, double weight) item)
    {
        this.Add(item.item, item.weight);
    }

    [...]
}
```

`IList<T>` derives from `ICollection<T>`. The `Add` method is declared in the base interface not the derived one.

Comment: Interesting, I would never have guessed that from the error messages.  
This solved my problem, I'll accept your answer as soon as SO allows me to.
Thank you!

Comment: Btw, do you know why this is that way? As IList<T> inherits from ICollection<T>, it shouldn't make a difference, no?

Comment: @Chillersanim: Explicit interface implementations don't exatly follow the normal inheritance rules. E.g. you can reimplement an interface. Also, it would be quite funny when an *excplicit* interface implementation *implicitly* assumes the base interface.